# Regarding props on react with GoogleMap ref={props.onMapLoad}

Tags: google-maps, reactjs

what am I passing in for props?
`props' is not defined      no-undef`

Documentation does not state what props is or suppose to be
https://github.com/tomchentw/react-google-maps

```
 import { GoogleMap, Marker } from "react-google-maps";  
  <GoogleMap 
    ref={props.onMapLoad}>    defaultZoom={3}
    defaultCenter={{ lat: -25.363882, lng: 131.044922 }}
    googleMapURL={googleMapURL}
    onClick={props.onMapClick}
    ))}
  </GoogleMap>
```

Answer (score 0):

found the answer here https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-google-map . 
take away lesson is to look for original codes and not some moded wrapper.

Comment: A link to a solution is welcome, but please ensure your answer is useful without it: [add context around the link](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there, then quote the most relevant part of the page you're linking to in case the target page is unavailable. [Answers that are little more than a link may be deleted.](//stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers)